# Loading 1 observable into another, but modifying both at the same time

Tags: knockout.js

in this function I have successfully passed the selectedItem observable to the function openAlertDialogueEdit.

```
openAlertDialogueEdit(selectedItem) {
        this.IsAlertDialogueInEditMode(true);
        this.EditingItemAlert(selectedItem);
        this.isAlertDialogueOpen(true);
    }
```

I am debugging the app and can see that changes made to the EditingItemAlert observable bound to the controls in the AlertDialogueEdit are done. But the original selectedItem observable is not changed. how can I achieve this behavior.

Note, the selectedItem is passed via:

```
 data-bind="click:function() { $parent.openAlertDialogueEdit($data)}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't that pass in the value of $data, rather than the observable itself? If you want to pass in the observable, you could try assigning an alias to the item in the foreach, or else use index to get the observable out of the parent collection directly:

```
data-bind="click:function() { $parent.openAlertDialogueEdit($parent.observableArray()[$index])}"
```

Comment: not really, looks as its the observable, this is the value of selected item:> selectedItem
{...}
    [Methods]: {...}
    [prototype]: {...}

Comment: Where are you setting a new value for it then?

Comment: in the forEach > <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: Alerts" id="alertsGrid">, I'll try the index thing..

Comment: I hadn't reference $parent.observableArray() correctly. Try this.

Comment: finally got this to work: **click:function() { $parent.openAlertDialogueEdit($parent.Alerts()[$index()])}**  does seem a bit scary though..